# GmailR - attachement won't allow body text to be displayed

Tags: r, email, gmail-api

I manage to successfully send HTML email with R with attachment.
However Gmail doesn't display the text.

```
email <-mime() %>%
to("recipient@example.com") %>%
from("sender@example.com") %>%
subject("This is a subject") %>%
html_body("<html><body>I wish <b>to</b> to see this in the body</body></html>")%>%
attach_file("file.csv")

send_message(email)
```

[image]

The screenshots shows the attachment but not the text, also if I check the email content

Originally I thought that the attachment may be visually covering the text, however after checking the html of the email received I concluded that it is not the case.

The same issue hapens on the gmail app on android

Thank you

Here is the orignal email ( I have stripped down the csv encrypted file to a manageable version)
     Original message

```
Message ID  <CAK4Nmip7J=zrxtqPCjnmnEOcA@mail.gmail.com>
Created on: 22 November 2016 at 12:43 (Delivered after 0 seconds)
From:   guillaume.lombard@company.com
To: guillaume.lombard@company.com
Subject:    Weekly Gifts report


Download original   Copy to clipboard   
Received: from 704816328917 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Tue, 22 Nov 2016 07:43:10 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 07:43:10 -0500
To: guillaume.lombard@company.com
From: guillaume.lombard@company.com
Subject: Weekly Gifts report
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=8ae9c0fed8a3
Content-Disposition: inline
Message-Id: <CAK4Nmgvip7J=zrxtQcqxOcA@mail.gmail.com>

--8ae9c04d036fed8a3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 12:43:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/csv; name=Gifts CVR.csv
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Gifts CVR.csv; modification-date=Tue, 22 Nov 2016 12:43:12 GMT

IiIsImRhdGUiLCJwYWdlUGF0aCIsIlNlc3Npb25zIiwiU0tVIiwiaXRlbVF1YW50aXR5IiwiaXRl
#
#
#
YS1naWZ0LXNldC10dWJlL253c2FiZ3MvIiwzLCJOV1NBQkdTIixOQSxOQQo=
--8ae9c0446fed8a3--
```

Comment: What happens if you use something simpler as `html_body`, e.g. `<b> I wish to see this </b>`

Comment: Same outcome, it doesn't show up

Comment: Can you share the output of "Show original" for the message?

Comment: I have attached the original email, any clues? Thanks @BrandonJewett-Hall

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the exact same issue and struggling to find any solutions online.

Comment: @GarAust89 I still haven't got to the bottom of this, however knowing I m not the only one suggests that there is likely an issue

Comment: I've got it @Guillaume, I'll post a solution now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was experiencing the exact same issue with attachments hiding the html body of my emails and after almost a day of searching I found a solution.

It turns out this is a known error with the gmailr package resulting from the boundaries of the MIME message not being placed correctly.

The workaround is to add attach_part after you specify your html_body to "add" your html body again. I'm not sure why this works but it does:

```
# Store html body as a variable
body <- "<html><body>I wish <b>to</b> to see this in the body</body> .   </html>"

email <-mime() %>%
to("recipient@example.com") %>%
from("sender@example.com") %>%
subject("This is a subject") %>%
html_body(body)%>%
attach_part(body) %>%
attach_file("file.csv")
```

For some reason adding `attach_part()` resolves the boundary issue or at least it did for me. You can monitor this issue on the Package Author's Git Account here: https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues

Although he hasn't committed anything new in over 6 months so it's unlikely to be resolved anytime soon. In the meantime the above work around should work for you!